# list of dictionary column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A column in my dataframe is list of dictionaries some thing like this:

How can I filter the rows that have specific value for the id key in tag column? for instance the rows that contains {"id" : 18}

Comment: Please reverse your post,  [do not just include picture of your data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557).

Comment: Having dictionaries as values in a dataframe kind of defeats the purpose of a dataframe, eh? I suggest fixing this issue upstream, by adding an `'id'` column to the dataframe. Any solution working with your current data structure will only make things worse.

Answer (score 3):

Since your `tag` column is list-valued, you could use `explode` if you are on pandas 0.25+:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['df','fg','ff'],
                   'tag': [[{"id" : 12} ,{"id" : 13}], 
                           [{"id" : 12}],
                           [{'id':10}]]
                  })

# make each row contains exactly one dict: {id: val}
s = df['tag'].explode()

# the indexes of interested rows
idx = s.index[pd.DataFrame(s.to_list())['id'].values==12]

# output
df.loc[idx]
```

Output:

```
    type    tag
0   df      [{'id': 12}, {'id': 13}]
1   fg      [{'id': 12}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample DatFrame**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'type':['dg','fg','ff'],'tag':[[{"id" : 12} ,{"id" : 13}] ,[{"id" : 12}],[{"id" : 29}]]})
print(df)

  type                       tag
0   dg  [{'id': 12}, {'id': 13}]
1   fg              [{'id': 12}]
2   ff              [{'id': 29}]
```

Then you can use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to check each cell:

```
df_filtered=df[df['tag'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([dict['id'] for dict in x]).eq(12).any())]
print(df_filtered)

  type                       tag
0   dg  [{'id': 12}, {'id': 13}]
1   fg              [{'id': 12}]
```